# Is the statement value += i; the exact same as value = value + i?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

Other than the extra space in the editor, is there any difference between the two statements?

EDIT: Thanks for the answers. I would also like to know how each statement is evaluated by the compiler.

Comment: I suppose you mean `value += 1` **or** `value = value + i`

Comment: For POD (like `int` or `double`) they evaluate as you would expect: identically. For anything else, they are evaluated by functions like `operator+(MyClass value, int i)` `operator+=(MyClass value, int i)`. So what happens depends on how the developer writes those functions. Any sensible person would make sure they 'work right` - but it's possible there are mistakes. I suggest you take a look at http://courses.cms.caltech.edu/cs11/material/cpp/donnie/cpp-ops.html or http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~jonmc/CSE2305/Topics/10.19.OpOverload/html/text.html for more accurate description.

Comment: If you don't mean, literally, "`value`" then there is a clear difference. Consider `*f() = *f() + i` versus `*f() += i`.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Editing your question to add more questions is not a good practice; in fact your EDIT has also been answered already. I think your question has been answered so please choose an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No - for anything other that PODs the operators may be overloaded.

You would hope that any reasonable implementation makes these operations the same, but it is up to the developer and not enforced by the compiler.

You can imagine even more subtle problems when people overload operators such that `(A==B)` is not the same as `(B==A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there can be differences.  Some objects, such as [Forward Iterators](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ForwardIterator/), define increment operators (`x++` and `++x`), but not not `operator+=`.  Some objects, like `string`, define `operator+=` but not increment.  But, generally, if `x += 1`, `++x`, and `x++` are all defined, they will do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Even for PODs they're not quite the same; the difference is trivial, but your helpful compiler writer may warn you for the latter but not for the former:

```
char ch = get_a_character();
++ch;
ch = ch + 1; // narrowing conversion
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, they are identical. It's highly probable that the compiler will generate the same code for both.

Unless one or both of the operators have been overloaded, of course. This is why some people frown on operator overloading.

Comment: I'd say that's a pretty controversial statement: I wouldn't trust the majority of C++ code in the wild (without double checking) - but I would say you can trust any built in types or quality libraries.